# Javascript Regular Expression and square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I need to get a number from.

this is my string:

```
alphanumeric|minlength[2]|maxlength[7]
```

I need to get the minlength number. (I don't always know what the minlength number will be)

How can I do this with a javascript regular expression?

Here's my full javascript code:

```
var attributes = e.attr('data-validate');
var pattern = /minlength\[(\d+)\]\/;
var params = attributes.match(pattern);
console.log(params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should match what you want.  And, it will capture the number in brackets that you want.

```
/minlength\[([^\]]+)\]/
```

Comment: sorry, I see my question wasn't detailed enough...I just added the strings alphanumeric and maxlength for filler.  I don't really know what those other strings will be.

Comment: @Steve, ah. Ok.  I edited.  That should still match what you want.

Comment: I'm getting a javascript error.  I updated my question to show my javasript code

Comment: the error i'm getting is: unterminated regular expression literal

Comment: also, does you reg exp search for only digits?  I need it to grab anything that could be between the square brackets.  thanks

Comment: @Steve, remove the last escape.  When I edited from my original i made the mistake.

Comment: @Steve, ok.  Now it will match anything in the brackets.